# How to calculate start date and end date for HTD(Half Year Till Date) in SAS? Is there any fucntion like intck or intnx which can help for my case?

Tags: time, sas

I am using below code but it isnt working:

```
date_end=intnx(DayofHalfyear,&CURRENT_DATE.,0,'b');
```

Comment: Show the values you would expect to see based on TODAY.  I looked at the SAS documentation for you and believe you may want SEMIYEAR.

Comment: Thank you. It worked!